# How to remove empty parameter or parameters anywhere in URL by .htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Empty parameters that I mean can be anywhere in URL each time different place, each time with different name, each time on different php page e.g :

```
http://www.example.com/AnyPHPpageHere.php?parameter1=7&parameter2=&parameter3=blue&parameter4=
```

to the form:

```
 http://www.example.com/AnyPHPpageHere.php?parameter1=7&parameter3=blue
```

So how to do it via .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this URL to remove any one or more empty parameters from anywhere in URLs:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?&)?[^=]+=(?:&(.*))?$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: There's an unexpected error when value of my queries contain special characters, like chinese language, ... e.g: 山西省 changed to: %252525E5%252525B1%252525B1%252525E8%252525A5%252525BF%252525E7%2525259C%25252581

Comment: Could you please look at my new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548049/301-redirect-old-parameter-names-to-new-element-names-by-htaccess

Comment: I need your help sir, there's a complicated to explain problem in your code. I'll try to explain: your code turns off my clean URL setting. before my clean URL was kw.html after adding your code it gets: search.php?color=kw&submit=1

Comment: That might be effect of other rules I think. I suggest posting a new question with your problem and I will attend.

Comment: I'll do sir, but before doing it, is there anyway to exclude submit= element in your code, I think this gonna works

Comment: try: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?&)?(?!submit=)[^=]+=(?:&(.*))?$`

Comment: new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777869/error-with-remove-any-one-or-more-empty-parameters-from-anywhere-in-urls-code

Comment: This is a real gem! It's a real shame that question like this one doesn't have 100s of upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /AnyPHPpageHere\.php\?product=7&keyword=&color=blue&city= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /AnyPHPpageHere.php?product=7&color=blue [NC,L,R=302]
```

If values of querystring are dynmic, you can use regex catpure groups :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /AnyPHPpageHere\.php\?product=([^&]+)&keyword=&color=([^&]+)&city= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /AnyPHPpageHere.php?product=%1&color=%2 [NC,L,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks but anyphppagehere means: Any PHP Page Name Here, not just specific page.

Comment: I fixed the question. You misunderstand my question, It was just an example in my question. I need general code.

Comment: @KevinSmith it means "yourPage.php" the page you want to redirect to .

Comment: No, It can be anything, query can be anything, elements can be anything, they also can appear anywhere and each time different places. e.g: http://www.example.com/DifferentPHPpageHere.php?parameter4=&parameter3=blue&parameter1=7&parameter2=

Comment: @KevinSmith Ok I understand, I will update my answer after 30mnts, actually I am very busy in a party.