# How to remove an element/parameter from URL by .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would remove color_new=any-value-could-be-here anywhere in URL via .htaccess
So how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule to remove a query parameter from any where in query string:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?&)?color_new=[^&]*(?:&(.*))?$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=302,L]
```

Keep this rule above other rules.

Comment: I use 302 for testing phase to avoid bad cache in browsers. Once you verify rule is working fine for you then you can change 302 to 301.

Comment: It works man! I really need your help on my last question, can you work on it as it's more complicated. thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34527744/how-to-remove-empty-parameter-or-parameters-anywhere-in-url-by-htaccess