# 301 redirect old parameter names to new parameter names by htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I just changed two parameter names and wanna redirect old names to changed name ones with any values anywhere in URL. e.g:

```
product.php?colornew=anyvalue&productname=anyvalue
```

301 redirect to:

```
product.php?color=anyvalue&product=anyvalue
```

Please note that this is just an example and as I said these two parameter can be anywhere in URL with any value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference capture groups of multiple RewriteCond in RewriteRule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784942/reference-capture-groups-of-multiple-rewritecond-in-rewriterule)

Comment: Did you check linked answer by Sumurai8?

Comment: yes, but couldn't find my answer yet

Comment: could help me to figure out how this is related to that question? As I understand that question is deleted the parameter name and only keeps the values. but my question is redirecting old parameter names to new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code to rename your query parameters in any URL:

```
RewriteEngine On

# rename query parameter colornew=>color
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?colornew=([^&]*)(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1color=%2%3 [NC]

# rename query parameter productname=>product
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?productname=([^&]*)(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1product=%2%3 [NC,NE,L,R=302]
```

Comment: Again fantastic job! just wondered if I delete: "product\.php$" from your code, isn't better if I want your code handle this job on any page?

Comment: Oh yes that's absolutely fine, you can use `RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1product=%2%3 [NC,NE,L,R=302]` to make this generic catch-all rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?colornew=([^&]+)&productname=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?color=%1&product=%2 [QSA,NC,NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: I want 301 redirect, also your code changed special characters. I think you need to use NE

Comment: Change R to R=301, Yes , NE flag is important to use if your querystring value contains some special chars.

Comment: Could you please change them in your code for better reference, thanks!

Comment: I really don't know how to do it, could you please complete the code that works with any URL with your QSA flag method.

Comment: I  changed the QUERY_STRING variable to THE_REQUEST, because the code was producing a redirect loop error.

Comment: QSA appends the full querystring to target path, so it is appending "path/?a=1&b=2&c=3" to /newpath/?d=4&e=5&a=1&b=2&c=3 , I dont think you want it.?

Comment: It doesn't redirect anything now

Comment: I just want the remaining of my URL remain unchanged and just that two old name elements get redirected to new names. But your code now not working

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix of anubhava's otherwise excellent answer:

```
RewriteEngine On

# rename query parameter colornew=>color
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?colornew=([^&]*)(&.*|)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1color=%2%3 [NC]

# rename query parameter productname=>product
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?productname=([^&]*)(&.*|)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1product=%2%3 [NC,NE,L,R=302]
```

The difference is, at the end of the rewrite condition, the question mark is removed and there is an added "or" operator: |.

The reason is that, without this change, the URL becomes product.php?color=anyvalue&product=anyvalue%3 when there is nothing filled by the final match - (&.*)? - because the question mark in that match section says it either exists or doesn't; and if it doesn't, %3 doesn't exist so it just becomes appended as a string. Instead, (&.*|) says the match can either be populated by an ampersand plus anything, or it can be populated by nothing. In this way, %3 becomes "" when there is nothing and %3 does not get appended to the string.