# Error with remove any one or more empty parameters from anywhere in URLs code

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This code is removing empty element or elements anywhere in URL but it turns my clean to dirty look URLs e.g. from http://www.example.com/US/FL/-show.html to http://www.example.com/search-products.php?productLocation=FL&countrySelect=US&submit=1

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?&)?[^=]+=(?:&(.*))?$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
```

My clean URL setting via .php is:

```
<select name="country" id="country" onchange="document.forms[0].action='<?php
echo $submit == 1 ? '/search.php' : '/index.php' ; ?>';document.forms[0].submit();return false;">
```

Full .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?&)?[^=]+=(?:&(.*))?$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=301,NE,L]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [L]




    RewriteRule (.*)/$ /?countrySelect=$1
    RewriteRule (.*)/+/(.*)-(.*)\.html$  search-products.php?countrySelect=$1&productSelect=$2&submit=1
    RewriteRule (.*)/tag/(.*) search-products.php?countrySelect=$1&keyword=$2
    RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)-(.*)\.html$  search-products.php?productLocation=$2&countrySelect=$1&productSelect=$3&submit=1
    RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)_(.*)\.html$  detail.php?name=$2&id=$3&detail=true&countrySelect=$1


</IfModule>



# Protect the htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

# Protect json
<Files ~ \.json$>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes
```

Comment: It was just an example, I mean the structure of clean url is gone

Comment: I used your code to delete empty parameters from dirty urls but my clean urls effected. (It works good with dirty urls.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing empty parameter removing rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(.+?&)?[^=]+=(?:&(.*))?\sHTTP
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=302,NE,L]
```

And test in a new browser.

Comment: Looks good, I will check more if any unexpected error will let you know. Thanks my friend.

Comment: Hi bro! I need your help with this complicated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968242/clean-url-for-multiple-parameters-anywhere-in-url-in-unique-sequence